# restriction in object of array in nestJS

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

i am trying to restrict data of object in array in nestJS where i am using mongoose for querying in mongodb.

i am expecting that a solution

a) Either there is an query in mongoose or nestJS to achieve it
b) Or there is any way to do this using typescript or javascript

for example -

```
const dataArray = [
{
id:1, 
post:'test 1' ,
createdBy : 'user1' 
details:'Some classified detail 1' 
},
{id:2, 
post:'test 2', 
createdBy : 'user2' ,
details:'Some classified detail 2'
}
]
```

Now if user 1 fetches the list data then it should receive:-

```
const dataArray = [
    {
    id:1, 
    post:'test 1',
    createdBy : 'user1',
    details:'Some classified detail 1'
    },
    {id:2, 
    post:'test 2', 
    createdBy : 'user2',
    }
    ]
```

Now if user 2 fetches the list data then it should receive:-

```
const dataArray = [
    {
    id:1, 
    post:'test 1',
    createdBy : 'user1',
    },
    {id:2, 
    post:'test 2', 
    createdBy : 'user2',
    details:'Some classified detail 2'
    }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const dataArray = [{
    id: 1,
    post: 'test 1',
    createdBy: 'user1',
    details: 'Some classified detail 1'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    post: 'test 2',
    createdBy: 'user2',
    details: 'Some classified detail 2'
  }
];


let filteredData = dataArray.filter(item => item.createdBy != 'user1');

console.log({
  filteredData
})
```

Comment: if you wanna to filter here you can modified as ur condition like
```
item.createdBy != 'your condition here'
```